# Nvidia multiple monitor with different resolution

Tags: nvidia, xorg, multiple-monitors

I have 2 monitor that have different resolution which is 1440x900 and 1360x768. But the default settings for my 1360x768 monitor in Nvidia-settings is 1024x768 and when I tried to change it to 1360x768 the screen is off the monitor or its out of it margin.

Here's my xorg.conf

```
# nvidia-settings: X configuration file generated by nvidia-settings
# nvidia-settings:  version 331.38  (buildd@fermium)  Tue Jan 14 12:07:21 UTC 2014

# nvidia-xconfig: X configuration file generated by nvidia-xconfig
# nvidia-xconfig:  version 331.49  (buildmeister@swio-display-x86-rhel47-10)  Wed Feb 12 21:00:07 PST 2014

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "0" EndSection

Section "Files" EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5" EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd" EndSection

Section "Monitor"

    # HorizSync source: builtin, VertRefresh source: builtin
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "CRT-0"
    HorizSync       28.0 - 55.0
    VertRefresh     43.0 - 72.0
    Option         "DPMS" EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GT 630" EndSection

Section "Screen"

# Removed Option "metamodes" "DVI-I-0: 1440x900 +0+0, VGA-0: nvidia-auto-select +1440+0"
# Removed Option "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "CRT-0"
# Removed Option "metamodes" "DVI-I-0: 1360x768 +1440+0, VGA-0: 1440x900 +0+0"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    #Option         "TwinView" "1"
    #Option         "TwinViewXineramaInfoOrder" "CRT-0"
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "CRT-1"
    Option         "metamodes" "DVI-I-0: 1360x768 +1440+0, VGA-0: 1440x900 +0+0"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24  Modes "1440x900" "1360x768"     Virtual 2800 900
    EndSubSection EndSection
```

Answer (score 0):

found this on this site for you:
http://www.howopensource.com/2012/10/install-nvidia-geforce-driver-in-ubuntu-12-10-12-04-using-ppa/

sudo apt-add-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa

sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install nvidia-current nvidia-settings

GeForce 600 series:
GTX 690, GTX 680, GTX 670, GTX 660 Ti, GTX 660, GTX 650, GT 645, GT 640, GT 630, GT 620, GT 610, 605